# arecord: set_params:1405: Unable to install hw params:

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to record audio from a microphone but I got below error. I tried `plughw:0,4` to get automatic sample format conversion and also given manually as `arecord -D hw:0,4 -d 5 -f S32_LE -r 48000 test.wav`, but I get same error.

When I run `alsamixer` I get this error as `ALSA lib ../../alsa-plugins-1.2.1/pulse/pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused cannot open mixer: Connection refused.` When I manually start `pulseaudio --start` alsamixer runs, but when I do some microphone related operation alsamixer repeats same error again.

```
arecord:
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_LE
- S32_LE

Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1405: Unable to install hw params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S32_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: 32
CHANNELS: 1
RATE: 48000
PERIOD_TIME: 125000
PERIOD_SIZE: 6000
PERIOD_BYTES: 24000
PERIODS: 4
BUFFER_TIME: 500000
BUFFER_SIZE: 4000
BUFFER_BYTES: 96000
TICK_TIME: 0
```

Comment: If `plughw` does not work, then this is a bug in your sound driver.

Comment: @CL Thank you. Is there anyway to find and fix it?

Comment: Did you write the sound driver yourself? Or did you buy an embedded board?

Comment: No, I haven’t write the sound driver. I have purchased an embedded board.

Comment: Provided with Yocto SDK.

Comment: Then you have to get support from whomever you have paid for that. In any case, there is not enough information for anybody else to debug the driver.

Comment: @CL mt8183 and mt6358 is the MPU & audio driver. Is there any other information needed?

Comment: That driver is written by MediaTek.

Comment: @CL Yes, it is.